# Python xml parsing from string return none attrib

Tags: python, xml

i

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.nexacroplatform.com/platform/dataset">
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter id="ErrorCode" type="string">-1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="ErrorMsg" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT" type="string">1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT_STR" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</Root>'''
tree=ET.fromstring(xml)
tree.findall('Parameter')
```

tree.findall('Parameter') returns empty list.

tree has none attrib and '{http://www.nexacroplatform.com/platform/dataset}Root' tag.
why this xml not work?

Comment: You need to fully qualify the parameter passed to findall with an appropriate namespace. You may find BeautifulSoup easier to work with

Comment: what is the information that you try to extract from the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (no external lib is involved in the solution)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.nexacroplatform.com/platform/dataset">
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter id="ErrorCode" type="string">-1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="ErrorMsg" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT" type="string">1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT_STR" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</Root>'''
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for entry in tree.findall('.//{http://www.nexacroplatform.com/platform/dataset}Parameter'):
    print(f'id={entry.attrib["id"]}, type={entry.attrib["id"]}, data={entry.text}')
```

output

```
id=ErrorCode, type=ErrorCode, data=-1
id=ErrorMsg, type=ErrorMsg, data= 정원을 초과하였습니다..!
id=O_RESULT, type=O_RESULT, data=1
id=O_RESULT_STR, type=O_RESULT_STR, data= 정원을 초과하였습니다..!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beautifulsoup` with **[`lxml`](https://lxml.de/)** parser to achieve what you want. I tried to print the `id`s of `<Parameter>` tags.

Here is the Code.

```py
import bs4 as bs
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://www.nexacroplatform.com/platform/dataset">
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter id="ErrorCode" type="string">-1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="ErrorMsg" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT" type="string">1</Parameter>
        <Parameter id="O_RESULT_STR" type="string">&#32;정원을&#32;초과하였습니다..!</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
</Root>'''

# Create a soup object with lxml parser
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')

# Select all the parameter tags
params = soup.find('root').find('parameters').findAll('parameter')

# Print the ids of all parameter tags
for i in params:
    print(i['id'])
```

```
ErrorCode
ErrorMsg
O_RESULT
O_RESULT_STR
```